# How can I handle a leap second correctly in my application

Tags: javascript, php, c, time, leap-second

I am creating applications and I'd like to know **how** I should/can handle a leap second. I'll try to describe the problem with a (hopefully) simple example situation. In this simple situation you could easily argue that an extra second of waiting time each +- 1.5 years may not be relevant but I still would sleep better knowing it works correctly/the way I want it too in 'all' situations :)

---

### Situation

---

*(We don't take any delays into account, so when a users presses a button it 'happens' immediately)*

You have a game in which you create soldiers.

- Each soldier takes 110 seconds to create.
- The users presses the button to create 1 soldier at `day 1 - 23:58:30`
- The user then expects the soldiers to be created `110s` later. Trough a normal '*DateTime calculation*'  your application would end up with `day 2 - 00:00:20`.

Now there happens to be a leap second between `day 1` and `day 2` --> `23:59:60`. Following this method the user will in actuality have waited `111s` for his soldier.

I'd prefer to use the Unix timestamp. This way you only have to add `110s` to the current time in seconds. But as far as I know this doesn't take leap seconds into account either. You'd still end up waiting `111s` in the actual time.

---

### Question

---

**What should I do to make sure a user or program is only waiting the time it should wait?**

*Is there a commonly used time stamp that does take leap seconds into account?*

*Should I always check if a leap second is ocurring?* *(may cause a lot of "waist" of cpu power?)*

EDIT: 
I mostly work in Javascript (Node.js) but an example in C, php or Python will work fine too!

Comment: Is accounting for leap seconds THAT important for your game? The last one happened in June 2015 and that was three years after the previous one. They can only occur twice a year. This is a pretty small edge case.

Comment: ... and even, standard unix time takes those leap seconds into account.  This is the difference between UTC and atomic time.  The leap second must be considered only to correct to local time, and only in the time (one second) window it is adjusting.  Unix doesn't know about atomic time, so you can sleep with quietness.

Comment: Thank you for your awnsers! Yes as I said for this use case it's probably not relevant but this is just a simple example:) But to provide a better use-case: In stocks exchange I think 1 second can make quite a difference since prices fluctuate quite heavily in a small time window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UTC time differs from atomic time in preciselly those leap seconds.  Without a reference to atomic time, you cannot detect from only UTC when a leap second has been inserted.  This makes the time in UTC "almost" continous, because of these little jumps of more than 0.5s and less than 1.0s that happen to disturb the time, when they happen.  UTC is defined as such to conserve calendar time and match it with earth movement, but despite of this, it can be considered continous by simply ignoring these leap seconds.

When a leap second is inserted, you simply note nothing in your clock, as only the atomic to utc clock difference has been corrected.  Only in the case you calculate planet or sattelite orbits, you have to correct to atomic clock, or you'll be inserting the whole leapsecond in your calculations (and make your orbits to change)  The actual effect is as UTC has been advanced one second by a phantom.  This only affects the numbering of seconds, that lose one more in the difference between atomic time and UTC.  But you notice nothing happening in your machine.  The difference in real time for timestamps that happen to be overlapped with the occurrence of the leap second are not affected, as the leap second insertion only affects the difference in numbering of atomic seconds and utc seconds.

In the case you were to consider time that overlaps the leap second (for example, in the calculus of orbital parameters of some extraterrestrial vehicle), then you have to take this extra second (that has not been counted for in atomic clock and yes in UTC time) and add it to the interval, or your calculus will be incorrect.  But astrophysics always do their calculus using the right timescale, so don't hesitate about space rubbish falling on your head by mistake.

If you use clock synchronization programs (like ntpd, for example) then the insertion of the leap second can happen in several ways:

- The second is inserted by adding one to the system clock at exactly the time of the leap clock insertion.  This makes weird things to happen, as timeout delays on these times are severely affected by the clock adjust that has been made.
- The clock is adjusted fast some time before the leap second (let's say two hours before) and adjusted normal again some time after the leap second. You'll have a continous scale of time, with seconds of a duration a little less than standard atomic time to adjust the time.
- Let the clock run.  The clock loop suddenly "sees" a one second offset between the reference (the "new" utc scale) and its internal clock, so it begins to correct it in a normal way (adjusting the clock speed).  This is the same as the previous one, but leads to more offset differences (one whole second against half for the previous point)

I don't know at this moment if your clock synch application follows the first or the second approach.  At least in linux I think the one used is the second or the third, and normally you don't notice it.

## NOTE

In the case you put as example, and supposing the worst case (the time synchronizes by making a step adjustment in the clock) you'll get the soldier created in 111s instead of 110s, but it is nothing to be worried upon, as **everything** in that lapse has happened in 111s instead of 110.  You'll get a `1.0%` more time to get your soldier, but everything has happened a `1.0%` slower in that same period, and your soldier has no actual penalties from other soldiers that happened to be conceived before or after the leap second.

And finally, if you don't use time synchronization programs, your clock will suffer more from it's actual offset (the difference of your clock's time and the actual time), than from the drift of making step adjustments to it.

Comment: Hi Luis Colorado, thank you for your clear and extensive answer already a vote up. I deduced as you said that also your whole OS will work slower, so from you application's perspective nothing weird is happening and it will work fine during this peroid. My only concern is that in actual time you wait longer than expected, in my use case it's fairly irrelevant but in stock exchange I can image this having quite some implication due to fast changes in prices.

Comment: Nope, What I said is that everywhere have accounted time the same as you.  You have a 100s delay time for a subject that last 101s.  But this happens all around the world.  So, your computer has not run slowlier, but everithing has behaved as if time had gone slower.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that in javascript. There are no leap seconds in javascript. ECMAScript 5, section 15.9.1.1 says:

> Time is measured in ECMAScript in milliseconds since 01 January, 1970 UTC. In time values leap seconds are ignored. It is assumed that there are exactly 86,400,000 milliseconds per day

Time values aren't guaranteed to be monotonic, and when a leap second occurs, they most likely won't be. In POSIX, you could use `clock_gettime` with a `clk_id` of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` (if `_POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK` is defined).

Answer (score 1):

You really should use timestamp here.

Timestamps are just number of seconds (all seconds, doesn't matter leap or not) that pass from predefined date (called "epoch"). It's just a counter.

It's immune to leap seconds, summer/winter time zone change and even insane government that change time zones border every year.

With timestamp, you always can calculate what time is now in UTC, GMT and Europe/Moskow (with leap seconds and with out them, it depends on your tz_data configuration). Reverse operation some times impossible to do.

Comment: Yes that's what I though as well using a timestamp, however the problem with leap seconds is that the OS will slow down the inner clock to align with the 'new' UTC time when a leap second has occurred. So it's not immune to leap seconds as you claim, as far as I understand it. Which means (also with the timestamp) the time between second e.g.: 1.000.000 and 1.000.110 will in the actual time have been 111s! This is exactly what I was trying to fix or counteract without 'waisting' cpu power

Comment: > Timestamps are just number of seconds (all seconds, doesn't matter leap or not) that pass from predefined date

This isn't true. The unix timestamp explicitly excludes leap seconds. It counts only 86,400 seconds for each day.

Comment: @Arnial this is just plain false. Timestamps are the number of seconds that have passed since epoch MINUS THE LEAP SECONDS.

To give an example, if you want to compute the time that has passed between 31 December 2016, 23:59:55 and 1 January 2016, 00:00:05 by subtracting the two timestamps, you'll get 10 seconds while in reality, 11 seconds have passed.

Answer (score 1):

Some RTLs support leap seconds. For instance, in Ada 2005 Ada.Calendar.Time supports leap seconds, although not obvious, only observable via child packages [Ada.Calendar.Formatting and Ada.Calendar.Arithmetic](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-9-6-1.html#p12). Also, Ada.Calendar.Formatting.Image writes ":59" for leap seconds and Ada.Calendar.Formatting.Value does not accept ":60".

In [the GNAT](http://getadanow.com/) targets not having native leap seconds support need "-y" binder key to turn it on. With this key I managed to work with leap seconds time even on Windows. I've made a [tiny library for conversion from UNIX time_t with or without leap seconds, and also formatting/parsing functions supporting leap seconds](https://bitbucket.org/OCTAGRAM/ada-calendar_conversions) to fully expose this feature of Ada standard. Of course, on Windows the inconsistency during the second is unavoidable, but difference between moments can be calculated properly, and operations on values obtained from elsewhere can be performed.

[Monotonic time](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-D-8.html) should be used to avoid shocks during the process. It should be used anyway, since user can change clock time, or time can be adjusted by synchronization, something happening much more often and much less predictable than leap seconds.

If you really need this, you can use the monotonic time to extrapolate the civilian one:

```
with Ada.Calendar;
with Ada.Real_Time;

-- ...

------------------------
-- Extrapolated_Clock --
------------------------

type Extrapolated_Clock is tagged record
   C_Clock : Ada.Calendar.Time := Ada.Calendar.Clock;
   RT_Clock : Ada.Real_Time.Time := Ada.Real_Time.Clock;
end record;

use all type Ada.Calendar.Time;
use all type Ada.Real_Time.Time;
use all type Ada.Real_Time.Time_Span;

procedure Synchronize (Object : in out Extrapolated_Clock);
function Extrapolate (Object : Extrapolated_Clock) return Ada.Calendar.Time is
  (Object.C_Clock + To_Duration (Ada.Real_Time.Clock - Object.RT_Clock));

-- ...

------------------------------------
-- Extrapolated_Clock.Synchronize --
------------------------------------

procedure Synchronize (Object : in out Extrapolated_Clock) is
begin
   Object.C_Clock := Ada.Calendar.Clock;
   Object.RT_Clock := Ada.Real_Time.Clock;
end Synchronize;
```

You might also need to make sure that captured moment of time can't be the leap second (the second after the captured one is not leap).